# React websocket.onmessage problems when accessing a variable from outside the scope

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, websocket

I have the following code in a parent component:

```
export default function CoreRegistry() {
    const tableList = ['region', 'sector', 'resource', 'skill', 'score', 'client', 'task'];
    const uuid = uuidv4();


    return (
        <MainLayout name='Core Registry' text='This area is used to manipulate the most basic data used by the system. Click an item in the accordion below to begin editing.'>
            <Accordion alwaysOpen>

                {tableList.map((name) => {
                    const title = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
                    const uuid = uuidv4();

                    return (
                        <Accordion.Item key={uuid} eventKey={uuid} variant="flush">
                            <Accordion.Header>
                                {title}
                            </Accordion.Header>
                            
                            <Accordion.Body style={{margin: '0px', padding: '0px'}}>
                                <div className='datatableContainer'>
                                    <Datatable tableName={name} />
                                    {/* <StickyHeadTable tableName={name}/>  */}
                                </div>
                            </Accordion.Body>
                        </Accordion.Item>
                    );
                })}

            </Accordion>
        </MainLayout>
    );
}
```

The child component (the relevant part):

```
function Datatable( { tableName }) {
    const websocket = useWebSocket();
    const auth = useAuth();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (websocket.socket === null) return;

        websocket.socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(json)
            console.log(tableName)
        
            const message = json.message;
            const area = json.area;
            const user = json.user;
        
            if (message === 'user_join' && area === tableName && user !== auth.user) {
                setUsers([...users, user]);
            } else if (message === 'user_leave' && area === tableName && user !== auth.user) {
                const newUsers = [...users];
                newUsers.splice(newUsers.indexOf(user), 1);
                setUsers(newUsers);
            }
        };
    }, [websocket.socket]);
```

It seems that the tableName that gets printed whenever any of the children receives a message is the same - and it is whichever is the last element on the parent's tableList (in this case, 'task'). I have no idea why this is happening, and how to fix it! Please help :)!

I tried many reworks, including using useRef, useMemo and useCallback. I was expecting the printed tableName to be a different one for each child component.